# Error while matching two strings in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i am working on the following batch code snippet. My objective is to compare two values and then print the respective message

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
@echo on 
setlocal

set test="hello"
if [%test%]==["hello"]
(echo ":mathced")
else ( echo "not matched")

timeout 10
endlocal
pause
```

but when i try to run it through cmd.exe, it gives me **error** saying

[image]

please provide the answers that will work on windows7 cmd.exe and are for batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spacing is everything. Your code is correct except for placement of some characters. Open parentheses need to be on the same line as the conditional and `)` and `else` need to be on the same line.

```
@echo on
setlocal

set test="hello"
if [%test%]==["hello"] (
    echo ":mathced"
) else (
    echo "not matched"
)
timeout 10
endlocal
pause
```

Answer (score 4):

Better would be

```
@echo on 
setlocal

set "test=hello"
if "%test%"=="hello" (
    echo matched
) else (
    echo not matched
)
timeout 10
endlocal
pause
```

The double quotes on assigning a value to a variable should be placed around "variable=value" as otherwise the double quotes are part of the assigned value.

The opening ( of an IF condition must be on same line as the IF keyword. The ELSE command must be on same line as closing ) of the TRUE branch of the IF condition. The opening ( of the ELSE branch must be on same line as ELSE keyword.